# Installing/Uninstalling Windows 8 UI Apps in Windows 8 for all users

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I'm using Windows 8 Pro 64 bit quite a while now. My account is the only Administrator account on the PC. There are 2 other standard (and local) accounts.

I've noticed that if I install an app from Windows Store, that app is only available from my start screen. Also when I uninstall an app that's common for all users (e.g., Finance), it only uninstalled from my account.

I want to install app and want it to be available for all users. When I'll uninstall an app, it should be removed for all users. No other user should have access to it. Just like installing/uninstalling programs on previous versions of Windows.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove Windows store apps that came with Windows 8 for all users:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Remove-ProvisionedAppxPackage /PackageName:microsoft.app1_1.0.0.0_neutral_en-us_ac4zc6fex2zjp
```

To find out the bit after /PackageName, use PowerShell:

```
get-appxpackage | ft packagefullName
```

That won't work with apps that a user downloaded from the store, because as 'hcl' said, they are part of the user's profile. You would have to run a script for each user. In there you could use the 'Remove-AppxPackage' PowerShell command to remove the app if it does not match a list of allowed apps.

Comment: this doesn't work in the RTM version. It only removes the user based app installation. The Apps are still installed in "C:\Program Files\Windows Apps" so that you can reinstall them later:

http://www.howtogeek.com/127274/how-to-restore-uninstalled-modern-ui-apps-that-ship-with-windows-8/

Comment: If you remove an App using Dism, and then create a new user, the user will not get that app and will also not be able to get it through the store. However if the user already existed at the time you removed the app, the app is registered with the user's store account and he/she can re-install from the store.

Answer (score 3):

It will be difficult, because programms are deployed/installed on a [per user Basis](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312021525/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/08/win8-howto-21-install-and-uninstall-metro-style-apps.aspx).
You can check this, if you go into the folder of a user's profile, show also the hidden directories and navigate then into the `\AppData\Local\Packages` folder. You will find all downloaded Windows Store Apps of the specific user.

Only if all users share the same cloud-account, the behaviour will probably be as you request. However this is surely not what you desire.

Comment: To get to `AppData\Roaming`, press `Windows + X`, click **Run** and type `%AppData%`. Go one level up from it, and click `Local`, then `Packages`.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov: Why Win+X / Run and not Win+R directly?

Comment: @Karan My bad, of course using `Win + R` is more effective.

Answer (score -1):

I have found an answer here:

Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage

try it and see if it works.